# How to convert a Z-height matrix into cartesian coordinates?

Tags: octave

I've run a FEMM simulation in Octave and as a result I got a quite large matrix with the following format:

```
resultMatrix =  0 90 120
                0 80 110
               10 80 100
```

In a normal carthesian system it would look something like this

```
result = [1, 1, 0;
          2, 1, 90;
          3, 1, 120;
          1, 2, 0;
          ...]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably computing the xy coordinates before so you should keep them from before so you don't have to recompute them now. Still, here's your answer:

```
octave:1> results = [0 90 120; 0 80 110; 10 80 100];
octave:2> col1 = repmat ([1; 2; 3], [3 1]); # repeat matrix
octave:3> col2 = ([1; 1; 1] .* [1 2 3])(:); # automatic broadcasting
octave:4> coords = [col1 col2 results.'(:)]
coords =

     1     1     0
     2     1    90
     3     1   120
     1     2     0
     2     2    80
     3     2   110
     1     3    10
     2     3    80
     3     3   100
```

Answer (score 2):

I will provide an alternate answer, which I suspect is what you need rather than what you're asking. Effectively your output is arranged in a grid and you want to assign coordinates to each element. Presumably you want to do this so that you can later plot a surface or something along those lines.

The most straightforward way to approach this in octave is to create a grid, e.g.

```
[Xindices, Yindices] = ndgrid( 1:size(resultMatrix,1) , 1:size(resultMatrix,2) );
```

This then allows you to plot a surface straightforwardly like this:

```
surface( Xindices, Yindices, resultMatrix );
```

Also note that, if you *really* want the output in the format you describe, you can easily obtain it from the above as well, by simply rearranging all the relevant n-dimensional arrays as vectors:

```
result = [ Xindices(:), Yindices(:), resultMatrix(:) ];
```